# Any account of the history of determinant of a matrix?

Tags: mathematics, mathematicians

Recently I got some knowledge of the so-called hyper-determinant discovered by Cayley.

It arose a lot of interest of determinant in my mind.

So, is there any good account of the history of determinant?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At [Alain Lascoux's web page](http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/~al/) you can find .pdf files of Thomas Muir's encyclopedic history of determinants. Muir devoted quite a bit of his long life to this work, which is only one of a very few essentially complete literature surveys ever done of a mathematical field of study. FYI, Dickson's multi-volume treatise **History of the Theory of Numbers** is another such literature survey that is essentially complete up to the time it was written.